# UPDATE set table with 3 different tables foreign key and primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have two different tables.

Department table

```
//Department
D#          DNAME
-------------------
1           SALES
2        ACCOUNTING
3          GAMES
5          SPORTS
```

Employee Table

```
//Employee
E#      D#
-----------
 1      3
 2      2
 3      5
 4      5
```

Now using Update statement , update the D#=5 to D#=3;

Currently using this statement

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET D# = 3 WHERE D# = 5;
```

But then i trying to learn that if i don't want update using D#, but want to update using the DNAME which mean E# from SPORT will change to GAMES , what should i do to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [`multi table update`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

Something along the lines of:

```
update employee e
  join department d using (d#)
   set e.d# = 3
 where d.dname = 'SPORTS';
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7aabd/1)